# Django form, overriding init, variable scope

Tags: python, django, forms, scope

In django, I have a form being called from the view, which is passed an extra object that popped in the form init. I want to use this object data (person) in the clean def's outside of init. How can I fix the scope of this passed information? Thanks!

```
class RegForm(forms.Form):
    first = forms.CharField(min_length=5)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        person = kwargs.pop("person")
        super(CompleteRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_first(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['first'] == person.first:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This information does not match records."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['first']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person` should be an instance variable:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.person = kwargs.pop("person")
    super(CompleteRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, in other methods, refer to it as `self.person` (not just `person`).

Answer (score -1):

You should assign it to `self`:

```
self.person = kwargs.pop("person")
```

This is fairly basic Python - you would probably benefit from doing a tutorial.

Comment: yes, I'm new to python.. familiar with the 'this' keyword in other languages. Might you recommend some concise references?